# In-App purchase trouble on Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm trying to enable an in-app purchase item on my app (already on Windows 10 store), but I always receive the same error message when trying to buy this item:

[image: This in-App Purchase item is no longer available in MyAppName]

> This in-App Purchase item is no longer available in MyAppName

The code is fairly simple and just what the docs recommend:

```
var itemName = "app.advanced_items.full";
if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[itemName].IsActive) {
    return true;
}
var results = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(itemName);

if (results.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded ||
    results.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.AlreadyPurchased) {
    return true;
} else { 
    return false;
}
```

More information:

- I created and submited the in-app item to the store before building the package as the documentation told me
- The name of the item is the same both on the store and the app (`itemName` on code)
- I tried this before submitting to the store
- I tried this after submitting to the store (My app is currently broken there! -- unable to buy the item)

I suspect the problem might be related with the following:

- The app display name (on `Package.appxmanifest`) is not the same app name on the store (The name I wanted was not available so I made it longer, but the app once installed will display the original name). This shorter name is the one in the error message...

I changed the "display name" to the full name of the app, but the error was the same. I don't know if sending it to the store might change this (I and don't want to deploy another buggy version just to test this theory)

Extra:
The only resources I found online about this issue were useless and related to Windows 8: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a401642f-1503-484e-9079-6b4cb72231df/this-inapp-purchase-item-is-no-longer-available-in-my-app?forum=wpdevelop)

Suggestions?

Comment: I have one consumable item appears as IAPs-premium and the Tag is premium and the key I use is also premium. So might be using dots and other symbols has a bug in somewhere, who knows

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello If only I could reliably test this before submitting the app to the store... I believe the store alters the package to include the in-app purchase information

Comment: In my cases, This message 'Choose another item' was displayed for several days after the certification of the IAP item. But later, the error msg was gone.

Comment: What is in the (await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync()).ProductListings?

Comment: @gregkalapos It returns an empty `IReadOnlyDictionary`. Should this work with the app on Visual Studio (I mean, not on the app store)?

Comment: This is a very good question, and I still did not find a documentation on this. What I can tell you is that I have an app in the store with IAP (works everything) and when I use it from VS (like working on the next freature, etc...) I see all my IAP in this list while i'm debugging from VS.

Comment: @gregkalapos I don't know if this should happen, but every time I try to generate app packages for the store, it makes me select my app in the "Select app name" dialog and it shows "Package Identity in the Windows Store" as None. It might be a problem in the store? -- When I open the "App Identity" link on my dashboard, it shows the "Package/Identity/Name" item correctly

Comment: I think it's not the root cause. I have many apps in the store, two of them use IAPs, one was migrated from Windows 8, it has this "package identity in the W. store" stuff, the other one was created as UWP, and for that I also have "none" like you... MS made some changes regarding this app identity and publisher stuff in UWP... maybe they have an issue with that, but other then that imho it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 2 months talking to Microsoft support they finally fixed something on their side and my IAP started working.

I believe the fix was global, but if your IAP still do not work, contact them to republish it.

Below is an excerpt from the email they sent me:

> We have issued a republish for your IAPs in this app. This should
>   correct the situation as soon as the process completes. You may want
>   to check periodically over the next few hours to see if you are able
>   to confirm the fix worked for you. Let me know what you see.

Comment: At last :) The problem was not with the code then :P

Comment: Yep, this is MS problem, new apps still has empty ProductLicenses collection, but ProductListing contains products, and new apps not have icons and screenshots when viewing it in WinPhone store app.

Answer (score 4):

Please check with the productId of the IAP. I guess the one you mention in your code is different from the one in the store.

If its the same, I recommend to use the method **LoadListingInformationAsync** which returns the list of IAP's and then select the required IAP from that list. **If there's a name mismatch then you wont be able to retrieve that IAP. So we'll be able to find its because of the naming problem.** 
I have also added a sample code for that. Give a try.

```
        try
        {
            var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
            var iap = listing.ProductListings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value.ProductId == "removeads");
            receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(iap.Value.ProductId, true);
            if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[iap.Value.ProductId].IsActive)
            {
                CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment(iap.Value.ProductId);
                //your code after purchase is successful
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //exception 
        }
```

Comment: The problem is, like I wrote on a comment above, my `ProductListings` is always an empty `IReadOnlyDictionary`... I have 3 IAP items on my dashboard and all of them are marked as published since several days ago. Yet I receive an empty object

Comment: did you create your IAP's in the new dashboard or you are using the ones you created in the old dashboard. If its the old dashboard then update the IAP and set it available to all markets available. Check out MSDN...seems like many are having this problem. [original MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a44b7364-4017-4d98-ad40-dcc03dac4311/cant-find-item-in-catalog?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required)

Comment: I created on the new dashboard

Comment: :( Please post the answer once you get this fixed :(

Comment: I am still having the same problem. Somehow, my app isn't being listed on store search... I believe there's a bug on the Windows store...

Comment: Resubmit your app and try after that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is that you need to differentiate between testing and production. You cannot use production mode unless you are published in the store. See [CurrentApp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp) and [CurrentAppSimulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator).

From the `CurrentAppSimiulator` page:

> Remarks
>
> Until the app has been listed in the Windows Store, the CurrentApp object won't work in the app. Use the CurrentAppSimulator to test your app's licensing and in-app products while you develop your app. After you test your app, and before you submit it to the Windows Store, you must replace the instances of CurrentAppSimulator with CurrentApp. Your app will fail certification if it uses CurrentAppSimulator.

Here is how I solve this in my app with a #define which I change for testing/production, and a proxy class that switches between CurrentApp and CurrentAppSimulator to make my other code much easier on the eyes.

*App.xaml.cs, App()*

```
            //
            // configure in-app purchasing
            //
#if false
#warning WARNING: You are using CurrentAppProxy in TEST MODE!
            CurrentAppProxy.SetTestMode(true); // true for test, false for production
#else
            CurrentAppProxy.SetTestMode(false); // true for test, false for production
```

*CurrentAppProxy.cs*

```
public static class CurrentAppProxy
{
    static bool? testmode = null;
    public static async void SetTestMode(bool mode)
    {
        testmode = mode;
        if (mode)
        {
            var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("WindowsStoreProxy.xml");
            if (file != null)
            {
                await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(file);
            }
        }
    }

    public static LicenseInformation LicenseInformation
    {
        get
        {
            if (testmode == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
            else if (testmode.Value) return CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
            else return CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
        }
    }

    public static IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<UnfulfilledConsumable>> GetUnfulfilledConsumablesAsync()
    {
        if (testmode == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
        else if (testmode.Value) return CurrentAppSimulator.GetUnfulfilledConsumablesAsync();
        else return CurrentApp.GetUnfulfilledConsumablesAsync();
    }

    public static IAsyncOperation<ListingInformation> LoadListingInformationAsync()
    {
        if (testmode == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
        else if (testmode.Value) return CurrentAppSimulator.LoadListingInformationAsync();
        else return CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
    }

    public static IAsyncOperation<FulfillmentResult> ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync(string productId, Guid transactionId)
    {
        if (testmode == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
        else if (testmode.Value) return CurrentAppSimulator.ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync(productId, transactionId);
        else return CurrentApp.ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync(productId, transactionId);
    }

    public static IAsyncOperation<PurchaseResults> RequestProductPurchaseAsync(string productId)
    {
        if (testmode == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
        else if (testmode.Value) return CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId);
        else return CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId);
    }
}
```

*Usage in my app...*

```
    private async Task RefreshInAppOffers()
    {
        // in-app offers
        List<KeyValuePair<string, ProductListing>> products = null;
        UnfulfilledConsumable unfulfilledConsumable = null;

        InAppOffers.Children.Clear();

        try
        {
            var listinginfo = await CurrentAppProxy.LoadListingInformationAsync();
            products = listinginfo.ProductListings.ToList();
            products.Sort((p1, p2) => p1.Value.FormattedPrice.CompareTo(p2.Value.FormattedPrice));
```

*CurrentAppProxy* is they key here.  If it works with the simulator, it should work with your production items. You just need to have all the other pieces in place for all the various conditions. Some testing is easiest to do in the debugger.

Comment: The thing is. I cannot use `CurrentApp` on production. It is very hard to believe that I can only use the CurrentAppSimulator even when my app is already published. Even the one I published on the store behave the same way with CurrentApp

Answer (score 1):

I tried contacting Microsoft about this issue and they asked me to make the IAP unavailable and then make it available again. **I must say it did not solve my issue**, but if you want to give it a try, follow these steps:

1. Create an update for the IAP
2. Under Distribution and Visibility set the IAP to Not available for purchase
3. Submit the update
4. Wait for update to publish
5. Create a new update for IAP
6. Set Distribution and Visibility back to Available for purchase
7. Submit the update
8. Once this update publishes, retest the IAP

After that, they told me to try making the whole app unavailable to all countries and publish it. Then do the opposite. No success either...

Answer (score 0):

i've got the same problem. In my situation the solution is to add all language description in IAP and then it's works fine

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with my new UWP app, "Midi Player". IAP was available for purchase on WP 8.1 right after certification and publishing but shows same error on W10M (Windows 10 Mobile) platform (I believe, all Windows 10 UWP apps has the same store).
I've opened issue with Microsoft but they can't help me. Fortunately, the issue now is gone :) What I did:

- published initial app revision
- created IAP
- tested IAP (works on WP8.1, not working on W10M)
- I found that my **Package.appxmanifest** file was changed slightly (that string **mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="7f32ab79-xxx-xxx-aff3-ce228745b36f" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"**) after publishing
- I changed version (minor number) and submitted new release with changed **Package.appxmanifest**
- today, I checked IAP on W10M Lumia 950 and it works.

So, my conclusion:

- you need to re-publish app **after** creating IAP
- you should wait for a little

Comment: I published the app after creating IAP (all the times) and waited two weeks... :(

Comment: Sorry about this; have you tried to contact store's customer support? MS store is kinda buggy, I still have a couple unresolved issues with it (and no hope to resolve 'cause support is very unprofessional)

Comment: Yes, support is very unprofessional there... I posted an [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34663266/754991) with my experience